# Customizing a functions success response / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I got this node.js code as an IBM Cloud function to let a user of my Watson Assistant send me a reminder via email. Works Great.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let smtpConfig = {
    host: 'hosthere', // you can also use smtp.gmail.com
    port: porthere,
    secure: false, // use TLS
    auth: {
        user: 'emailhere', 
        pass: 'passwordhere'
    }
};

function main(params) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let response = {
            code: 200,
            msg: 'E-mail was sent successfully!'
        };

        if (!params.reminder) {
            response.msg = "Error: Reminder was not provided.";
            response.code = 400;
        }
        else if (!params.email) {
            response.msg = "Error: Destination e-mail was not provided.";
            response.code = 400;
        }
        else if (!params.conversation_id) {
            response.msg = "Error: Conversation id was not provided.";
            response.code = 400;
        }
        if (response.code != 200) {
            reject(response);
        }

        console.log(`Validation was successful, preparing to send email...`);

        sendEmail(params, function (email_response) {
            response.msg = email_response['msg'];
            response.code = email_response['code'];
            response.reason = email_response['reason'];
            console.log(`Email delivery response: (${email_response['code']}) ${response.msg}`);
            resolve(response);
        });

    });
}

function sendEmail(params, callback) {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);
    let mailOptions = {
        from: `Watson Assistent Message <${smtpConfig.auth.user}>`,
        to: params.email,
        subject: `REMINDER: ${params.reminder}`,
        text: `Do it!`
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {

        let email_response = {
            code: 200,
            msg: 'Email was sent successfully',
            reason: 'Success'
        };

        if (error) {
            email_response.msg = 'Error';
            email_response.code = 500;
            email_response.reason = error;
        }
        else {
            email_response.msg = info.response;
            email_response.code = 200;
            email_response.reason = info.response;
        }
        callback(email_response);
    });
}
```

I just need to customize the response shown at ‚Results‘ after a successful request. So I can print to the user something like ‚Email sent successfully’ (if it actually was successful)

When calling the function it gives me this:

```
Results:
{
  "code": 200,
  "msg": "250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=1N0Fxf-1lzPHJ457n-00xO6a",
  "reason": "250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=1N0Fxf-1lzPHJ457n-00xO6a"
}
Logs:
[
  "2021-01-20T23:11:38.706021Z    stdout: Validation was successful, preparing to send email...",
  "2021-01-20T23:11:39.117946Z    stdout: Email delivery response: (200) 250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=1N0Fxf-1lzPHJ457n-00xO6a"
]
```

The thing is, this whole answer printed to „msg“ is nowhere defined in the code. Actually there is a defined answer for a successful request in the code, it just doesn’t get printed.

Why is that? How could I change that?

With the error response everything works fine. The defined answers from the code get printed at ‚results’ :

```
Results:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "msg": "Error: Destination e-mail was not provided."
  }
}
Logs:
[
  "2021-01-21T09:47:14.531598Z    stdout: Validation was successful, preparing to send email..."
]
```

What is wrong with the success message?

Comment: Where/how do you call `main`?

Comment: to test function and get results: and logs: shown, I can invoke with parameters inside the IBM cloud functions web interface. parameter needed are: "email" : "anyemailaddress", "reminder" : "just text", "conversation_id" : "1234–1234–1234" @eol  In real-world application these parameters will be sent via webhook from Watson assistant to function - which works fine as well - just want to customize the response shown for a successful sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define:

`msg: 'Email was sent successfully',` in `email_response`

Its simply being overwritten by the `if/else`.

If you want the *Email was sent successfully* message (or if not okey) do something like:

```
callback(error ? {
  code: 500,
  msg: 'Error',
  reason: error
} : {
  code: 200,
  msg: 'Success',
  reason: info.response.includes('okey') ? 'Email was sent successfully' : info.response 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this to get a generalized message,

```
function sendEmail(params, callback) {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);
    let mailOptions = {
        from: `Watson Assistent Message <${smtpConfig.auth.user}>`,
        to: params.email,
        subject: `REMINDER: ${params.reminder}`,
        text: `Do it!`
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {

        // Sets the response object, changing it to a generalized message.
        let email_response = 'Email was sent successfully';

        if (error) {
            email_response = 'Email was not sent successfully';
        }

        callback(email_response);
    });
}
```

Call the sendEmail like this,

```
sendEmail(params, function (email_response) {
            response = email_response;
            resolve(response);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @hasan Unfortunately this will cause results: to be just empty. {} just the brackets, nothing else shown. :/  I'd say it has something to do with the main function, not with the sendEmail...

Comment: or do I have to change something in the main function as well to make your code work? Cause logs: is showing this "2021-01-21T14:27:27.582610Z    stdout: Email delivery response: (undefined) undefined",

Comment: Please check, I think this is all you can do from you posted code.